# Summation: Adding all scores with a min and max (score) of 10 and multiply by (amount of Issues) Y - Notation Formatting Advice

Tags: summation, notation

I am new this portal and haven't done any maths for a very long time.

For an academic project I am working on, I attempting to create a equation (not even sure that's the right language to use) where I get a sum of all the scores and multiply by the amount of issues.

here is an example for a use case:

| Issues (Y) | Score (X) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0-10 |
| 2 | 0-10 |
| 3 | 0-10 |
| 4 | 0-10 |
| 5 | 0-10 |
| 6 | 0-10 |
| 7 | 0-10 |
| 8 | 0-10 |
| 9 | 0-10 |
| 10 | 0-10 |

I have given this a go learning what I can about the notations, but what I am looking to achieve is:

Issue Score = sum of all the scores * the amount of issues = 1000

So I wast sure what the "rules are" or how this would look:

$$
\sum_{??}^{y} x\leq 10
$$

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If $n$ is the number of issues, what you are looking for is $$n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$ where $x_i$ is the score of $i$th issue. It's not clear whether you want this to be an equation or inequality. Should this be equal to $1000$?

Comment: Thank you for your response!  In the use case above, yes, I would be looking to equal 1000.   From just doing a little googling I am looking for an equation.  thanks again.

Comment: Would I not need to show that X can only be between 0 and 10?

Comment: You can specify a condition that $0 \le x_i  \le 10$ and that $n \ge 100$ (if you want this to be equal to $1000$)

Comment: Amazing thank you!